# Passing parameter in Restful webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, get

Dear Stackoverflow users,
I have been playing around with restful webservice for quite a while now.
I have a small doubt in how to pass a parameter using GET method.
As get can only be used to retrieve any resources, how is it possible to pass parameter.
I have written a small code for this, but there seem to be something wrong with the code.

```
@GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/instrumentname/")
    public String getname(String name1) {
try {


String [] env=null;
            String[]callAndArgs= {"python","connection.py",ins_name};//passing the parameters

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs,env,
                    new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Balkishore\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testinstrument_Rest\\build\\web"));//excuting the python file



            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 

                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));//getting the input



            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 

                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));//getting the error




           interface_name = stdInput.readLine();//reading the output




                System.out.println(interface_name);


    }


        catch (IOException e) {//catching the exception

            System.out.println("exception occured");

            e.printStackTrace();

            System.exit(-1);

        }
        return this.interface_name;
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks a ton in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: You can use @Queryparam annotation to read url parameters. If this is what you are looking for then refere to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198043/restful-webservices-query-parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to concatenate parameters at the end of the URL in following format: 
www.xyz.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3

where param1, param2 are parameter names and val1,val2 are values for the corresponding parameters...  You can just type them in a browser's URL bar instead of writing an HTML page or a script for testing...

Also, you are right in saying that GET is Generally used to fetch resources from a web server, but at times you have to pass information whose resource has to be fetched...

Comment: thank for replying mate!! But what if i have a java client linked with my server? In this case i cannot pass the parameter via URL. I have to some how embed the parameter into my GET method right? If not what could possibly done in the above code to pass parameter? Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And one more thing i am not using any kind of database.

Comment: this code is a server side code right?? now do you want to know how to pass parameters from client to server?? or you want to know how to pass the parameters from this function to python script which are invoking as a shell command??

Comment: I want to know how to pass the parameter from this function to the python script. Thanks for replying mate.

Comment: if i know this, i could also pass the parameter from server to java Jframe client. And by the way, yes it is server side code mate.

Comment: mate i have posted one more question here in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348788/passing-parameter-from-get-function-to-python-script-in-restful-server could you please give me some hint? i am badly stuck in this phase. Without this i cannot proceed further.

Comment: problem is in the approach itself. Thats why please read carefully and give me individual answers to all questions? 1) are you aware of basic client/server programming? 2) the piece of code you are writing runs at server end or client end?

Comment: thank you very much mate but i figured out the answer myself!!