# RESTful webservices: query parameters

Tags: rest, path, resteasy

I am using JAX-RS with RESTEasy.

I want to know if we can have represent different resources with path differentiated only  by order and number of query parameters?

e.g.

```
/customer/1234
/customer?id=1234
/customer?name=James
```

Can I create three different methods e.g.

```
@Path("customer/{id}")
public Response get(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {
..
}

@Path("customer?id={id}")
public Response get(@QueryParam("id") final Long id) {
..
}

@Path("customer?name={name}")
public Response get(@QueryParam("name") final String name) {
..
}
```

Will this work, can I invoke different methods by differentiating path like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid `@Path`:

```
@Path("customer/{id}")        // (1)
```

These are not:

```
@Path("customer?id={id}")     // (2)
@Path("customer?name={name}") // (3)
```

They are the same because the boil down to

```
@Path("customer")
```

which you could use.

So you *can* have `(1)` and one of `(2)` and `(3)`. But you *can't* have `(2)` and `(3)` at the same time.

`@QueryParam` parameters are *not* part of the `@Path`. You *can* access them as you do in the signature of the method but you can't base the routing of JAX-RS on them.

**Edit:**

You can write *one* method that accepts both `id` and `name` as `@QueryParam`. These query parameters are optional.

```
@Path("customer")
public Response get(@QueryParam("id") final String id,
                    @QueryParam("name") final String name) {
    // Look up the Customers based on 'id' and/or 'name'
}
```